# jenkins ant invocation and ivy tasks

Tags: ant, jenkins, ivy

I have one jenkins installation on a os x server (Lion) and i want it to invoke an ant script to compile one sigle example project.

The istallation has one dedicated user, "jenkins", and if i log him from an ssh instance i can successfully run the compile task (which is using ivy's tasks) with:

```
jenkins>ant compile
```

Problems start when ant is invoked by the web interface, getting this error:

```
Problem: failed to create task or type antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant:resolve
```

The cause: ant does not load correctly ivy's *resolve* task from the library. I really can't understand the fix. I am sure jenkins runs the commands as the "jenkins" user.

**edit: more information**

```
BUILD FAILED
/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/example-build/workspace/build.xml:19: Problem: failed to create task or type antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant:resolve
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
No types or tasks have been defined in this namespace yet
This appears to be an antlib declaration. 
Action: Check that the implementing library exists in one of:

    -/usr/share/ant/lib
    -/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/.ant/lib
    -a directory added on the command line with the -lib argument

Total time: 0 seconds
Build step 'Invoke Ant' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: please post the complete stacktrace, it looks like maybe the ivy library is not in ants classpath

Comment: Where did you install ivy's jars?

Comment: via homebrew, _which ivy_ outputs **/usr/local/bin/ivy**

Answer (score 3):

Looks like ANT installation used by the Jenkins job cannot pick up the ivy jar.

## Option 1

Add the following target to your ANT build and invoke it once to install the ivy jar into a location that ANT will recognise, namely $HOME/.ant/lib

```
<target name="bootstrap" description="Install ivy">
    <mkdir dir="${user.home}/.ant/lib"/>
    <get src="https://repository.sonatype.org/service/local/artifact/maven/redirect?r=central-proxy&amp;g=org.apache.ivy&amp;a=ivy&amp;v=LATEST&amp;e=jar"
         dest="${user.home}/.ant/lib/ivy.jar"/>
</target>
```

Notes:

- This target uses the REST API provided by Sonatype's Nexus repository, to download the latest version of ivy.

## Option 2

If the ivy jar is located in the following directory:

- /usr/local/bin/ivy

You can invoke ANT with the **lib** parameter to specified alternative locations for ANT plugins.

```
ant -lib /usr/local/bin/ivy clean build
```

Answer (score 0):

When you Run Ant task, in the classpath ensure that ivy.jar is there. In the eclipse -> Run As-> Ant Build -> Edit configuration -> Classpath tab. Even though Eclipse would have the ivy.jar in the ANT Home, for some reason it's not called.